# Why is my local project not being pushed to github repository?

Tags: node.js, git, github

I have a node app in my local machine, which works totally fine on localhost, i have tried to push the code to github repository, if it didn't work, i created new repos and tried again

I even adopted both methods to push using git bash:
using ssh and http

In my .gitignore file i have written node_modules/
But every time i get the same error message and code is not pushed to my github repo, the error is :

```
$ git push -u bb4 main
Enter passphrase for key '<path for ssh key>':
Enumerating objects: 2484, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2484/2484), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2457/2457), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2484/2484), 272.37 MiB | 679.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2484 (delta 492), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (492/492), done.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 7eaa2fe7b701a22ea9b13333b122831363593fb6a0ce25c557df3aa90fa29f9e
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File mongod.pdb is 367.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File mongos.pdb is 247.35 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:ritish73/bb4.git'
```

it shows two too large files **mongod.pdb** and **mongos.pdb**, where are these files coming from , i thought they might be in node_modules but i have already added that to .gitignore file.

There is also a .git(hidden) directory inside my project directory which is a local repo of the project handled by vscode itself, Could it be causing some issue? (though i did add this to .gitignore too, still didn't work).

What could be the problem here? Happy to hear your thoughts and resolve this error. This is my directory structure where i run git bash.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly github doesnt allow too big files, you got that right.

You also added `node_modules` to your `.gitignore` which is good, too.
You shouldnt add your `.git` directory, tho, since this is created when you ran `git init` - this directory is essential for your local git repository.

I guess that you added your `node_modules` in some previous commit, thus it is added in your history, meaning that the resulting diffs would be pushed to the repository.

You would have to alter these commits to exclude `node_modules` but for the sake of simplicity it would just create a new git repository (by deleting `.git` and run `git init` again)

Comment: i deleted the .git directory and did everything from start , it works fine now

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be so called Github hook to deny your push, see `[remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)` error message.

Whoever initialized the repository (maybe you), set up a [custom git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) to do some pre-checks before anything is pushed.

Comment: That's the normal GitHub hook that prevent you to push big binaries.